# Python: no attribue __hash__

Tags: python, class, hash, set, getattr

Instances of `PackOfPersons` have a `__getattr__()` function that, for example: `PackOfPersons.say_name()` will call `Person.say_name()` for `Person` instances inside `PackOfPersons.person_objects()`.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def say_name(self):
        print 'my name is', self.name

    def add_to_set(self):
        PersonObjectSet.add(self)

class PackOfPersons:
    def __init__(self, person_objects):
        self.person_objects = person_objects

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        def _group_helper(*args, **kwargs):
            for person in self.person_objects:
                getattr(person, item)(*args, **kwargs)

        return _group_helper


PersonObjectSet = set([])
PackObjectSet = set([])

a = Person("Albert")
b = Person("Bernie")
c = Person("Catherine")
p = PackOfPersons([a, b, c])
p.say_name()
PackObjectSet.add(p)
```

The last line throws an error which is traced back to:

```
line 18, in _group_helper
    getattr(person, item)(*args, **kwargs)
AttributeError: Person instance has no attribute '__hash__'
```

How do I work around this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by declaring `class PackOfPersons(object):`